# Jquery window.load not working

Tags: jquery

```
$("#footer_privacy_policy").click(function(){

    window.location = "aboutus.php";    

    $(window).load(function(){

              alert("window is loaded");

             $(".about").load("./about/privacy_policy.txt");
     });
});
```

So I loaded the page "aboutus.php" when I perform a click on the id,
but the alert never pops up.
Any one could help with this problem?

Comment: Does `$("#footer_privacy_policy")` actually select something?

Comment: ye the page gets reloaded to aboutus.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as you set the url with `window.location`, the page is reloaded so the `$(window).load()` never happens as it is inside the click event callback.

Is there a reason you are using `window.location` instead of relying on the `href` attribute and linking to a page with the content already inside?

Comment: so is there a way to load the page then do my thing?

Comment: You could add different classes/ids to the `<body>` tag on each page, check what class/id the `<body>` has on dom ready and then load in your text files based on that. Seems a bit clunky though as you are reloading the whole page already.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `window.location`, the browser immediately navigates to that page. No further code on the current page is executed after that point. In fact, any event handlers or callbacks that you've set on the current page are wiped out.

Comment: so is there a way to load the page then do my thing?